# Use SKSpriteNode(s) Multiple Times From An Array

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

The app I'm working on has multiple nodes which are added repeatedly to the game. What I have been doing is creating new SKSpriteNodes using an array of texture, and once the node has been added, I assign that node with a specific physics body. But what I would like to do is instead of a having an array of textures, have an array of SKSpriteNodes with the physics body pre-assigned.

I believe I have figured out how to do this, the problem I have is when I try to add that SKSpriteNode more then once to the scene.

For example, below is I'm been playing around with, which works, but if I add another line of addChild(arraySegment_Type1[0] as SKSpriteNode), I get an error and the app crashes.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

    var arraySegment_Type1:[SKSpriteNode] = []
    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myimage")

    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(sprite.size.width, sprite.size.height))
    sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    sprite.name = "mysprite"

    arraySegment_Type1.append(sprite)

    addChild(arraySegment_Type1[0] as SKSpriteNode)

}
```

Does anybody know how I would be able to load SKSpriteNodes multiple times from an array?

Comment: you want to load the same SKSpriteNode multiple times into the scene?

Answer (score 5):

What your code does at the moment is the following:

- Creates an empty array of the type [SKSpriteNode]
- Creates a single SKSpriteNode instance
- Ads a physicsBody to the sprite
- Ads this single spriteNode to an array
- Picks out the first object in the array (index 0) and ads it to the parentNode.

Your app crashes because you are trying to add the *same* `SKSpriteNode` instance to the scene several times over.

---

Here is a reworked version of your code that actually ads several sprites to the scene, it technically works but does not make a lot of sense just yet:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // your ARRAY is not an array-segment it is a collection of sprites
    var sprites:[SKSpriteNode] = []

    let numberOfSprites = 16 // or any other number you'd like

    // Creates 16 instances of a sprite an add them to the sprites array
    for __ in 0..<numberOfSprites {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myimage")
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
        sprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        sprite.name = "mysprite" // not sure what your plans are here...
        sprites.append(sprite)
    }

    // picks out each sprite in the sprites array
    for sprite in sprites {
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

Now as I said this doesn't make all that much sense. As you've probably noticed the sprites all appear on top of each other for one thing. **More importantly**, doing this all in the `didMoveToView` means it makes very little sense going through the whole array-dance, you could simply do the following instead:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let numberOfSprites = 16 // or any other number you'd like

    for __ in 0..<numberOfSprites {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myimage")
        // skipping the physicsBody stuff for now as it is not part of the question

        addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

An improvement obviously, but all sprites are still covering each other, and `didMoveToView` might not be the best place to handle all this anyway, so perhaps something like this to illustrate the point:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let sprites = spritesCollection(count: 16)
    for sprite in sprites {
        addChild(sprite)
    }
}

private func spritesCollection(#count: Int) -> [SKSpriteNode] {
    var sprites = [SKSpriteNode]()
    for __ in 0..<count {
        var sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myimage")
        // skipping the physicsBody stuff for now as it is not part of the question

        // giving the sprites a random position
        let x = CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.width))
        let y = CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(size.height))
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        sprites.append(sprite)
    }
    return sprites
}
```

Now, long-wound as this is it is still just a starting point towards a working and more sensible code-structure...

Comment: I'm working on landscape mode, I have added 10 sprites , among which few of them are not visible. Could you please tell me how to position every sprite inside the screen.

Comment: `actually ads several sprites` - "adds" is spelled wrong